# Transform list in a dataframe (breaking elements by interval of rows)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to append a list to a dataframe in Python
I want to put the first 6 numbers on the same line and then add it line by line, until complete the dataframe.
*I tried to generate the data to make it easier:*

```
import pandas as pd
import random

randomlist = []
for i in range(0,30):
    n = random.randint(1,30)
    randomlist.append(n)

resultado(randomlist)
randomlist = 30, 11, 18, 11, 28, 18, 22, 18, 20, 10, 11, 6, 29, 1, 11, 15, 3, 4, 17, 11, 17, 18, 27, 25, 11, 10, 7, 4, 18, 27

lista_colunas = ['Carro', 'Moto', 'Barco', 'Patinete', 'Mobilete', 'Skate]
lista_index = ['Entre 1 a 5', 'Entre 6 a 10', 'Entre 11 a 15', 'Entre 16 a 20', 'Entre 21 a 25']
```

**Expected outcome:**

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest directly using NumPy instead.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# 1, 30 are the boundaries of the values;
# (5, 6) is the shape of the resulting matrix
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 30, (5, 6)), index=lista_index, columns=lista_colunas)
```

Result:

```py
>>> df
               Carro  Moto  Barco  Patinete  Mobilete  Skate
Entre 1 a 5       20     8     24        21        29     15
Entre 6 a 10      16     3     29        29        21     27
Entre 11 a 15     25     8     27        29        25     23
Entre 16 a 20     18    27     22         3        23      7
Entre 21 a 25     22     2      2        17         4     12
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to firstly reshape your list and afterwards give the arguments to the dataFrame. This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

randomlist = [30, 11, 18, 11, 28, 18, 22, 18, 20, 10, 11, 6, 29, 1, 11, 15, 3, 4, 17, 11, 17, 18, 27, 25, 11, 10, 7, 4, 18, 27]

lista_colunas = ['Carro', 'Moto', 'Barco', 'Patinete', 'Mobilete', 'Skate']
lista_index = ['Entre 1 a 5', 'Entre 6 a 10', 'Entre 11 a 15', 'Entre 16 a 20', 'Entre 21 a 25']

randomlist = np.reshape(randomlist, (len(lista_index), len(lista_colunas)))
df = pd.DataFrame(randomlist, index = lista_index, columns=lista_colunas)

print(df.head())
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: to reshape, i did this:
N = len(lista_index)
    lista_resultado_agrupado = [randomlist[n:n+N] for n in range(0, len(lista_colunas), N)]
  
but, I couldn't fill the table    
for k in range (0,30):
        result.at[lista_index[i], lista_colunas[j]] = lista_resultado_agrupado[i][k]
        result
This did not work =/

Comment: With numpy is a lot easier. But if you want without it you need to write:

N = len(lista_colunas) 
lista_resultado_agrupado = [randomlist[n:n+N] for n in range(0, len(randomlist), N)].
Then use lista_resultado_agrupado as data to the data frame. It works.